# Set destination directory in linux

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to copy the executable from build directory to custom directory.
In windows I am able to achieve it but linux its not working.

```
win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): DLLDESTDIR +=  $$PWD/../Bin/debug
else:win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): DLLDESTDIR +=  $$PWD/../Bin/release

else:unix:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): DLLDESTDIR +=  $$PWD/../Bin/debug
else:unix:CONFIG(release, debug|release): DLLDESTDIR +=  $$PWD/../Bin/release
```

Linux executable is created in build directory but not copied to the above mentioned dir.

Answer (score 1):

Dll is windows only so possibly try DESTDIR flag for binary on Linux - http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#destdir